# Cannot read property 'arrayToDataTable' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am using Google API for generating pie charts in my JSP page but I am getting the following Error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrayToDataTable' of undefined"`

Following is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
    <%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils" %>
    <%@ page import="java.nio.file.Files"%>
    <%@ page import="java.nio.file.Files"%>
    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.WildcardFileFilter"%>
    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.DirectoryFileFilter"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> 
    <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%> 
    <%@page import = "javax.servlet.*,java.text.*" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script>

        // Load google charts
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        //google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        // Draw the chart and set the chart values
        function drawChart(Passed,Failed) {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Task', 'Passed/Failed'],
                ['Passed', Passed],
                ['Failed', Failed],
            ]);

            // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
            var options = {'title':'EPRISM automation Status', 'width':400, 'height':300};

            // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

    </script>

    <style>
        .box{
            display: none;
            hide: { fixed: true }
            width : 100%;
        }

        a:hover + .box,.box:hover 
        {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 100; 
            hide: { fixed: true }

        }
        #rajaram {
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #rajaram td, #rajaram th {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        #rajaram tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

        #rajaram tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

        #rajaram th {
            padding-top: 12px;
            padding-bottom: 12px;
            text-align: left;
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
    <%!
        String fname ="";
        int passed = 0;
        int failed = 0;
        HashMap<String,Integer> hm = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    %>
    <center><h1>EPRISM DASHBOARD</h1></center>
    <form id="cvision" name="cvison" action = "/db/rajakannuri" method="POST" >
        <center><table id="rajaram" style="width:50%">

        <tr>
            <th>CARRIER</th>
            <th>DATE</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id ="ram">
        <%
        try { 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eprism_dashboard";
                String username="root";
                String password="@1RAJAram1.@";
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT CARRIER_NAME FROM eprism_reports");
        ResultSet resultSet =  pstmt.executeQuery();
        %>
        <Center>
            <td>
                <select name="release" id="module">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select CARRIER</option> 
                    <option value = "ALL">ALL CARRIERS</option>
                    <%
                    while(resultSet.next()) {
                        fname = resultSet.getString("CARRIER_NAME"); %>
                        <option value="<%=fname%>"><%=fname%></option>

                    <% } %>
                </select>
            </td>
        </center>

        <%
        connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println(e);
        } 
        %>
        <Center>
            <td><input type="date" id="datepicker" name = "dateFrom" onchange="this.form.submit()"/></td>
        </center>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </br>

        <%
        if(request.getParameter("release")!=null)
        {
            String tagName = request.getParameter("release");

            try{                         

                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eprism_dashboard";
                    String username="root";
                    String password="@1RAJAram1.@";
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            if(!(request.getParameter("release").equals("ALL"))) 
            {
                PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement("SELECT  *,CLAIM_TYPE FROM eprism_dashboard.eprism_reports where CARRIER_NAME='"+tagName+"'"+ 
                "AND RERUN = (SELECT MAX(RERUN)"+ 
                "FROM eprism_dashboard.eprism_reports Where CARRIER_NAME ='"+tagName+"')");

                ResultSet resultSet =  pstmt.executeQuery();
                    hm = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
                %>
                <table border="2">
                <tr>
                <td>CARRIER_NAME</td>
                <td>CLAIM_TYPE</td>
                <td>STATUS</td>
                <td>DATE</td>
                <td>RERUN_COUNT</td>
                </tr>
                    <%
                    while(resultSet.next()){
                    %>
                    <tr><td><%=resultSet.getString("CARRIER_NAME")%></td>
                    <td><%=resultSet.getString("CLAIM_TYPE")%></td>
                    <td><%=resultSet.getString("STATUS")%></td>
                    <td><%=resultSet.getString("DATE")%></td>
                    <td><%=resultSet.getString("RERUN")%></td></tr>
                <%
                    } 
                    %>
                </table> 
                <%
            } else {
                PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) as STATUSCOUNT, status FROM eprism_dashboard.eprism_reports where CARRIER_NAME!='QA_EPRISM' GROUP BY  Status");
                ResultSet resultSet =  pstmt.executeQuery();
                hm = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
                while(resultSet.next()){
                    hm.put(resultSet.getString("status"),resultSet.getInt("STATUSCOUNT"));
                }

                if(hm.get("Failed")==null)
                {
                    passed =hm.get("Passed");
                    failed = 0;
                }
                else if(hm.get("Failed")==null)
                {
                    passed = 0;
                    failed = hm.get("Failed");
                }
                else {
                    passed =hm.get("Passed");
                    %><%=passed%><%
                    failed =hm.get("Failed");
                    %><%=failed%><%
                }
                %>
                <script language="javascript"> drawChart(<%=passed%>,<%=failed%>)</script>
                <%
            }
            connection.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                out.println(e);
            } 

            hm = null;
            tagName = null;

        }
        else
        {
            %><Center><h3>Please select and Enter all details</h3></Center><%
        }               
        %>

        </table>
        <div id="piechart" align="left"></div>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Please, can anyone help me on this issue. I tried searching for this error on google I have found so many answers but none of them worked.

Comment: Dont see any library for `google.visualization`

Comment: @brk I tried but not working